# ACL on virtual interface get ignored

Tags: cisco, router, acl

Good evening!

Recently i've got some problem in configuring cisco router (IOS 12.x). There is an virtual interface for a vlan:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.203
 description Department XXX
 encapsulation dot1Q 203
 ip address 10.0.0.193 255.255.255.192
 ip helper-address 192.168.0.3
 ip access-group v203in in
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip flow ingress
 ip flow egress
 ip virtual-reassembly
end
```

and there is an extended access-list:

```
ip access-list extended v203in
 deny ip any any log
```

And all is brilliant. Computer connected to some trunc port via cisco switch can't get it's ip-address from dhcp server and can't access the network.

Now we will do some magic:

```
no ip access-list extended v203in
ip access-list extended v203in
 permit udp any any eq 67
 permit udp any any eq 68
 deny ip any any log
```

Oh, good, our computer have got it's IP-address... but... wait, what the hell?!
(sorry for cyrillic output, it's trivial to understand):

```
C:\>ping ya.ru
Обмен пакетами с ya.ru [93.158.134.3] с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 93.158.134.3: число байт=32 время=2мс TTL=55     
Ответ от 93.158.134.3: число байт=32 время=2мс TTL=55
```

`tracert ya.ru` says `reply from 10.0.0.193: host is unreachable`.

Can please any one explain to me this 'magic' or how the packets flows thru ACL?

---

Workstation's ip is 10.0.0.194/26, gateway is 10.0.0.193.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The only thing you are allowing on the interface is DHCP, so a traceroute _should_ fail.

Comment: Yes, but should not ping fail too? It's working. And the websites are also available.

Comment: In other words: the _only thing_ that have been blocked is a traceroute.

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, and you could block ICMP, too. Traceroute uses UDP, and the only UDP you are allowing is DHCP.

Comment: Does `deny ip any any log` block tcp, udp and icmp, doesn't it? Should it block web site access from browser?

Comment: I think ICMP is blocked separately in some IOS versions. Blocking IP should block both TCP and UDP, hence HTTP and HTTPS will be blocked.

Comment: since the  tracert is blocked , then the ICMP is blocked

Comment: may be the gateway is diffrent than your router? what about in the first case if assign static IP to the PC , is it able to ping ?

Comment: @Mr.lock, looks like ACL blocks only the DHCP. With a single 'deny' line and a static IP it work's the same (ping and web is working).

Comment: how about traceroute

Comment: traceroute still blocked.

Comment: @Mr.lock, Cisco uses UDP, not ICMP, for traceroute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug in iOS 12.4. Other device with 15.x doesn't have that problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your ACL is only allowing DHCP (ports 67 and 68). ICMP, which is what ping uses, doesn't operate at layer 4 therefore it doesn't have a port number. Traceroute uses a port in 30,000's range (I forget the exact number). The ACL statement you have is blocking all ports except port 67 and 68. Hope this helps.